# WCF Service where a class implements multiple interfaces

Tags: wcf, proxy

Consider the following situation:

I've multiple interfaces for e.g. `IService1`, `IService2`, `IService3`... All interfaces are implemented by a single class - `MainService`.

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, reliableSessionEnabled: true);
string address1 = "net.tcp://localhost:9000/ep1";
// create other addresses with ep2, ep3 and so on...

ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceLibrary.MainService));
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, address1);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService2), binding, address2);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService3), binding, address3);
// and so on...

serviceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Running...");
Console.ReadLine();
```

At this point I have multiple endpoints for this service host instance. To create a client instance, I do the following --

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, reliableSessionEnabled: true);
string address = "net.tcp://...:9000/ep1";

ChannelFactory<ServiceLibrary.IService1> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, address);
IService1 channel1 = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
// create other channel factories and other channels and now we have channel1, channel2, channel3
```

These channels are basically proxies that I can call functions on. But these proxies are interface specific. `channel1` will not call any other methods except for the ones defined in `IService1`.

What I need is a super proxy that can call any methods defined in any of the interfaces `IService1`, `IService2`, `IService3` and so on.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Having a single interface inherit all the other interfaces is something that is not possible. Let us just assume that the services have already been developed and all I can do is tinker with the creation of service host and the channel.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE** This solution won't work for the OP (original poster), but I'll leave it here for future readers that may be looking at how to do this when implementing a new service.

The only way I can think of to do that is to create an new interface that inherits the other interfaces, like this:

```
public interface IMasterService : IService1, IService2, IService3
{

}
```

Then you can implement `IMasterService` in your service and only need a single endpoint:

```
public class MainService : IMasterService
{

}

serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMasterService), binding, address1);
```

Now you have a single interface (`IMasterService`) that you can use with `ChannelFactory<T>`:

```
ChannelFactory<ServiceLibrary.IMasterService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMasterService>(binding, address);
IMasterService channel1 = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: Actually that's thought did come into my mind, but unfortunately that cannot be done.

Comment: Consider some DLLs that have already been packaged that implement some services. But if I could dynamically using reflection create an interface that would inherit all of these, that is something that is possible.

Comment: Ah..got it.  I thought you meant it couldn't be done in .NET; I see you've edited your post to clarify the situation.  I'll leave my answer for future readers who may not have that limitation, but I'll edit it to note that it won't work in your situation.  Sorry. :(

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for your help Tim. :)

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll noodle the problem a little while longer and post something if I get an idea that might help you directly.